# ml.net model works with console application but not web api

Tags: asp.net-web-api, ml.net, ml.net-model-builder

I have created an MLModel with ml.net model builder and it works with a 'consume' console application  and hard coded values for input. I wanted to go to the next step and feed values with web api. I am using a modified version of their tutorial example on using a mlmodel in a web api. When I use postman with the webapi I get the following error;

System.InvalidOperationException: 'Could not apply a map over type 'Single' to column 'PG' since it has type 'String''

The mlmodel builds successfully from model builder and the default code is generated from the model builder. Running a consume console app  with hard coded values  on the model works.

Here is the relevant code for modelinput

//*****************************************************************************************
//*                                                                                       *
//* This is an auto-generated file by Microsoft ML.NET CLI (Command-Line Interface) tool. *
//*                                                                                       *
//*****************************************************************************************

```
using Microsoft.ML.Data;

namespace JobClassMLModelML.Model.DataModels
 {
    public class ModelInput
    {
        [ColumnName("EducationLevel"), LoadColumn(0)]
        public float EducationLevel { get; set; }


        [ColumnName("Experience"), LoadColumn(1)]
        public float Experience { get; set; }


        [ColumnName("OrgImpact"), LoadColumn(2)]
        public float OrgImpact { get; set; }


        [ColumnName("ProblemSolving"), LoadColumn(3)]
        public float ProblemSolving { get; set; }


        [ColumnName("Supervision"), LoadColumn(4)]
        public float Supervision { get; set; }


        [ColumnName("ContactLevel"), LoadColumn(5)]
        public float ContactLevel { get; set; }


        [ColumnName("FinancialBudget"), LoadColumn(6)]
        public float FinancialBudget { get; set; }


        [ColumnName("PG"), LoadColumn(7)]
        public string PG { get; set; }


    }
}
```

And here it is for modeloutput

//*****************************************************************************************
//*                                                                                       *
//* This is an auto-generated file by Microsoft ML.NET CLI (Command-Line Interface) tool. *
//*                                                                                       *
//*****************************************************************************************

```
using System;
using Microsoft.ML.Data;

namespace JobClassMLModelML.Model.DataModels
{
    public class ModelOutput
    {
        // ColumnName attribute is used to change the column name from
        // its default value, which is the name of the field.
        [ColumnName("PredictedLabel")]
        public String Prediction { get; set; }
        public float[] Score { get; set; }
    }
}
```

I cloned the modelinput and modeloutput classes in equivalent webapi classes of jobclassdata and jobclassprediction respectively

The console application that works:

```
using System;
using Microsoft.ML;
using JobClassMLModelML;
using JobClassMLModelML.Model.DataModels;

namespace ConsumeApp
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        { // Load the model
            MLContext mlContext = new MLContext();
            ITransformer mlModel = mlContext.Model.Load("MLModel.zip", out 
var modelInputSchema);
            var predEngine = 
mlContext.Model.CreatePredictionEngine<ModelInput, ModelOutput>(mlModel);

            // Use the code below to add input data
            var input = new ModelInput();
            // input.

            input.ContactLevel = 5;
            input.EducationLevel = 5;
            input.Experience = 5;
            input.FinancialBudget = 5;
            input.OrgImpact = 5;
            input.ProblemSolving = 5;
            input.Supervision =5;
            //input.PG = "PG01";

            // Try model on sample data
            ModelOutput result = predEngine.Predict(input);
            Console.WriteLine($"Predicted value: {result.Prediction} ");

        }
    }
}
```

Here is the code for the predict controller

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Extensions.ML;
using JobClassMLModelWebAPI.DataModels;

namespace JobClassMLModelWebAPI.Controllers
{
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class PredictController : ControllerBase
    {

        private readonly PredictionEnginePool<JobClassData, 
JobClassPrediction> _predictionEnginePool;

        public PredictController(PredictionEnginePool<JobClassData, 
JobClassPrediction> predictionEnginePool)
        {
            _predictionEnginePool = predictionEnginePool;
        }

        [HttpGet]
        public JobClassData Get(JobClassData jobClassData)
        {
            return new JobClassData
            {
                // insert test data here
            };
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult<string> Post([FromBody] JobClassData input)
        {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
             {
                return BadRequest();
            }

            JobClassPrediction prediction = 
_predictionEnginePool.Predict(input);

            string PredictedJobGrade = prediction.Prediction;
            return Ok(PredictedJobGrade);
         }    
    }  
}
```

Here is json body code posted

```
{
    "educationLevel": 3,
    "experience": 3,
    "orgImpact": 3,
    "problemSolving": 3,
    "supervision": 3,
    "contactLevel": 4,
    "financialBudget": 4,
    "pg" : "PG01"
}
```

The expected result would be predicted paygrade such as PG03. Instead the error is

System.InvalidOperationException: 'Could not apply a map over type 'Single' to column 'PG' since it has type 'String''

at the line

```
            JobClassPrediction prediction = 
_predictionEnginePool.Predict(input);
```

with no compile error and with console app working is the format of the json input?

Thanks

Comment: Does the console app still work with `input.PG` uncommented?

Comment: Did you model PG as a string or as an numeric with Model Builder?

Comment: The console app still works with input.PG uncommented. For the web api uncommented or commented doesnt work either way

Comment: In the code I provided above, it was modelled(defined) as string for  model builder. And the generated code confirmed that for modelinput and  modeloutput class defns. In a separate solution and project I even tried doing model builder on the PG being numeric just in case. Console app worked their too with reqd changes in telling it the prediction was float etc instead of string. In  both cases in came up with similar error messages. In the numeric example , it had something about Uint32(0-9) not being convertible to single.

Comment: In both examples , console application worked but the  web api using postman  didnt